# First party cookie on samesite and cross origin

Tags: javascript, cookies, samesite, cross-origin-read-blocking

Lets say

(A) - I have a website at domain name: testbuy.com

(B) - I have a separate application hosted on app.testbuy.com

(C) - I have a javascript hosted at cdnjs.com/testscript.js

When a user visits testbuy.com, it downloads the js testscript.js(C). This javascript(C) makes POST requests to app.testbuy.com (B). Lets say it sends every time the page is loaded or the user clicks on "Buy" button.

Let's say when the first request is made to app.testbuy.com, it(B) sets a cookie with SameSite attribute. On the subsequent requests, this cookie will be sent to the server.

In this context:

1. Is this treated as 1P cookie? Though the javascript is downloaded from cdnjs which is not samesite.
2. If I host the javascript in app.testbuy.com/js/testscript.js, Does this change the way the cookie is treated?
3. How does this vary across Safari, Chrome and Firefox?

This [article](https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/#remote-resources) talks about remote resources as javascripts downloaded. Are these for javascripts downloaded from cross-origin or does it apply to satesite as well?

Comment: It does not matter where the Javascript is loaded from, what matters is the domain of the HTML page, in your case `testbuy.com`.

Comment: Thanks, So, if I am visiting testbuy.com and the js sends a request to app.testbuy.com and server at app.testbuy.com sets a cookie, is it considered first party cookie or third party cookie?

Comment: That depends on whether `app.testbuy.com` and `testbuy.com` have the same [registrable domain](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-registrable-domain). See also the examples in the definition of [same-site](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#same-site).

Comment: Yes, they both have the same registrable domain testbuy.com and they are "same-site". However, the url on the address bar is "testbuy.com" while the server which is setting the cookie is "app.testbuy.com". Is this considered 1P cookie?

Comment: If they have the same registrable domain, this counts as a 1P cookie.